# How can I input accent words in a PHP script interaction?

Tags: php, linux, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, command-line-interface

I am writing a PHP script which is intended to run in a Linux Terminal in order to drop variable results in a text file.

Everything seems to be working fine but when I run the script and it shows the input lines in a terminal I can't write accent words including the single accent tilde (`´`) and accented letters like `á é í ó ú`.

Here's the portion of code I am using to accept the user input:

```
<?php
$cuantos = readline("Cuantas veces? ");
$cadena = readline("Escriba el Texto: ");
$separar = readline("Incluir separadores? ");
$separar = strtoupper($separar);
$archivar = "";
for ($x = 1; $x <= $cuantos; $x++) {
        if ($separar=="S") { $archivar = $archivar . "Texto ".$x."\n";}
        if ($separar=="S") { $archivar = $archivar . "----------------------------------\n";}
        echo  $archivar = $archivar . $cadena\n;
        if ($separar=="S") { $archivar = $archivar . "==================================\n";}
}
file_put_contents('textos.txt', $archivar);
?>
```

A screenshot of the script running in a terminal is shown here:

[image]

Please notice that the text should read **`Este texto debería tener acentos pero en la terminal no está aceptando ningún caracter con tilde.`**, nevertheless it is not showing any accent in the text.

I have already tried using the `<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>` and some other tricks for charsets in order to make the `readline` to accept accent's with no success. I have also tried changing `php.ini` default charset and no success so far.

I can write the accent letters in a terminal without problem as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

After inserting `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` as suggested, no luck yet.

[image]
[image]

Perhaps something's wrong with my terminal but that made me think this should work on a tty terminal, or not? So I tried and I got the same results.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you write those letters in the shell itself ?

Comment: Yes I can. Every accent letter is showin in a terminal with no problem. Please see the screenshot I recently added. Thank you.

Comment: add internal encoding at top level of your code `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: No luck with the `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Works for me. It could be your terminal settings or you need to issue some settings to the terminal before doing the readline.

Comment: You are right, I am having the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 but it works correctly on Mac. I found a possible solution, will let you know shortly.

Comment: I have also tried in gnome-terminal

Comment: I have tried in a TTY terminal with the same results. Maybe something system-wide configurable? Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED
[image]

The problem is that default php package on Ubuntu 14.04 uses libedit which was originally written for BSD. It has a bug and the workaround requires replacing libedit with readline.

Here are the bug reports:

1. https://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-userlevel/2011/01/26/msg004486.html
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libedit/+bug/816758

Solution:

I created a Debian package with corrected build. It works successfully on Ubuntu 14.04 and solves the problem with accent letters.

1. cd /tmp
2. git clone https://github.com/mitghi/php5
3. cd ./php5
4. dpkg -i -B --force-depends --force-overwrite php5_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17_all.deb
5. php5enmod readline
6. dpkg -i php5-readline_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17_amd64.deb

Note:

In case of dependency errors, run : `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Ok, this procedure seems easier and faster than the previous one. Nevertheless I had to use `php5enmod` instead of `php5enmode` in step 5. And I faced some dependencies issues which I solved by running `sudo apt-get -f install`, after which all dependencies got satisfied and the solution was installed. Thank you very much for your efforts, time and patience. My install process can be viewed right here: http://pastebin.com/qrBPA5LJ

Comment: Glad that it worked, you are welcome. I edit to post and add those steps you mentioned.